# Simple way to display chosen images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a simple way for a user to select a list of files for upload and have them display on screen before he decides to upload them.

This is the sort of logic I've been trying:

```js
function printFiles(){
  var inp = document.getElementById('selected');
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
    var img = new Image();
    var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
    img.src = name;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Upload new File</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p>    
  <input type=file name=file id=selected onclick=printFiles() multiple>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
```

This doesn't work and when I print the variable inp to the console, it shows  null, as it's null until selected. 
Is there a way to pass the file names to the function and display them on the page only after the user has clicked 'choose files' and then 'open'?

Comment: Look into www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Updated script with no error run time error: http://jsfiddle.net/zkhu0bfL/3/

Answer (score 0):

you have an error inside the loop, on inp.files.item you shoul use [i] instead of (i), this is and array of selected files on the input tag

```js
function printFiles(){
  var inp = document.getElementById('selected');
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
    var img = new Image();
    // var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
    var name = inp.files.item[i].name;
    img.src = name;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Upload new File</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p>    
  <input type=file name=file id=selected onclick=printFiles() multiple>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it with javascript [FileReader Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
function printFiles(){
  var inp = document.getElementById('selected');
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
       displayImage(inp.files[i]);
  }
}

function displayImage(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
       var img = new Image();
       img.src = reader.result;
       document.body.appendChild(img);
    });
}
```